# How to remove uncategorised posts from WordPress

Tags: headers, categories

I am using koresponsive theme. I am displaying name of categories as my menu bar just below my header. Now I need to remove 'Uncategorized' category from displaying it in the menu bar. How can I do it? What is the code.Please help me.

Here is my `header.php`. I guess I have to change in `wp_list_categories`. I tried many ways. But it is not working.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <?php $options = get_option('koresponsive'); ?>
   <html class="no-js" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
<?php kore_meta(); ?>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
<?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<?php kore_head(); ?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
    <?php if (is_front_page()) { ?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#slides').slides({
        preload: true,
        preloadImage: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/loading.gif',
        play: 5000,
        pause: 2500,
        hoverPause: true,
        generatePagination: false

    });
});
</script>
  <?php } ?>      
  </head>
 <?php flush(); ?>
  <body id ="blog" <?php body_class('main'); ?>>
<header class="main-header">
    <div class="container">

        <div id="header">

            <?php if( is_front_page() || is_home() || is_404() ) { ?>
                    <h1 id="logo">
                        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
                    </h1>  <!-- FINE #logo -->
            <?php } else { ?>
                    <h2 id="logo">
                        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a> 
                    </h2>  <!-- FINE #logo -->
            <?php } ?> 
             <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar')
     || !dynamic_sidebar('Top Widget') ) : ?>
        <?php endif; ?>         
        </div><!--FINE #header-->
        <div class="second-nav">
                <nav id="navigation" >
                    <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary-menu' ) ) { ?>
                        <?php wp_nav_menu(   array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'container' => '' ) ); ?>
                    <?php } else { ?>

                        <ul class="menu">
                            <?php wp_list_categories('title_li='); ?>

                        </ul>
                    <?php } ?>
                </nav>
            </div> 
    </div><!--container-->        
     </header>
   <div class="main-c">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the argument to exclude the 'Uncategorised' category using this:

```
<?php wp_list_categories('title_li=&exclude=XX'); ?>
```

where XX is the ID of the category to exclude.

Here is the codex page
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Include_or_Exclude_Categories

Comment: thank you lucio.I tried it it.BUt it didn't worked.I am not able to get category id.

Comment: the id of the 'Uncategorised' category is 1. `wp_list_categories('exclude=1&title_li=');`